# I want to add annotations to jOOQ generated classes

Tags: java, code-generation, pojo, jooq

I would like to add some annotations to generated **pojo** and **dao** classes. I know that I can override

```
JavaGenerator.printClassAnnotations(JavaWriter out, SchemaDefinition schema)
```

but problem is that this method is called for every generated file. I don't know how to limit my changes just for **pojo** or **dao** since I am not getting **mode** passed in :( Is there some other way? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is currently not easily possible to customise the generation output on this level.

A major rewrite of the code generator is planned for jOOQ 4.0, and custom annotations will definitely be part of it. Until then, I can think of these workarounds:

- Implement some text-based post processing that patches annotations into the generated files at the appropriate positions
- Override the `JavaGenerator`, replacing the relevant methods with a patched version
- Patch the `JavaGenerator` with your own custom logic

The last two workarounds will be the most powerful, although (obviously) at the risk of breaking at every minor release.

Comment: I was afraid you say that, I have already some post-processing groovy script, but I was hoping to get rid of it and extend the generator.

Comment: @Tomas: We'll be working on this, soon. But until now, it hasn't been a priority yet. The complexity of getting this right is rather high...